# Reading bytestream and writing to file

Tags: java, inputstream

Currently I have this implementation working reading from a bytestream and writing out to file. I am wondering if this is particularly dangerous or discouraged against, in the essence of time I'm unable to test all the different implementations of this mechanism and this seems to be working. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
SharedByteArrayInputStream stream = (SharedByteArrayInputStream) content;
ArrayList<Byte> bites = new ArrayList<Byte>();
byte bite = 0;
while((bite=(byte) stream.read())!=-1){
    bites.add(bite);
}
byte[] bytes = new byte[bites.size()];
for(int x = 0; x < bites.size(); x++){
    bytes[x] = (byte) bites.get(x);
}
String aloha = new String(bytes, Charset.forName( "ISO-8859-1" ));
writer.append(aloha+"\n");
stream.close();
```

I know it looks silly but it works.

Thanks again for any input

Comment: Do you have a requirement to turn the byte stream into a string, or do you just need to write the data to a file?

Comment: I wouldn't say dangerous but it is certainly inefficient. First you read the bytes one by one (you could use a buffer) and secondly there is no need for the conversion. You can just dump the bytes to the file and convert them when reading them back.

Answer (score 2):

```
File f = new File(//PATHFILE);
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(f);
            InputStream is=//InputStream
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            int count;
            while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
              fOut.write(data, 0, count);   
            }
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            is.close();
```

That's my code and works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're only creating the temporary ArrayList because you cannot determine the length of the input. Try using ByteArrayOutputStream instead.

Consider the following code:

```
SharedByteArrayInputStream stream = (SharedByteArrayInputStream) content;
ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

//Reading in chunks is better performance-wise than reading one byte at once.
int r;
byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1000];

//Read and write into the ByteArrayOutputStream
while((r = stream.read(buffer) != -1){
    bOut.write(buffer, 0, r);
}

String aloha = new String(bOut.toByteArray(), Charset.forName( "ISO-8859-1" ));
writer.append(aloha+"\n");
stream.close();
```

Your code uses a lot more memory than necessary and iterates through two loops when only one is required making it very inefficient. The ByteArrayOutputStream is a better implementation that is both more efficient and probably has a smaller memory footprint.

Comment: Your code is using more memory than necessary too. The `ByteArrayOutputStream` is storing bytes read from `stream` in heap just as the List was. Writing directly from `stream` to `writer` is more efficient.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison It's cleaner... and I'd assume the complex nature of a ArrayList causes it to use more memory than a ByteArrayOutputStream. I did write "probably has a smaller memory footprint" not "definitely has a smaller footprint".

Comment: very true, all good points, +1. Think a good solution here depends on what he's processing. If its lots of data, your solution isn't the best, and might not even work. For small data sets this is a fine solution.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Yep... His post wasn't exactly clear what he was doing... Reading data from a stream and then sticking it all into a string... only to use a phantom writer object which he never flushes or closes.... Hmm... I'm starting to doubt that the reading is his biggest problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems, I'll list them in order of importance.

1. You are reading an entire byte stream into `bites`, then writing `bites` to another stream (possibly the disk.) This is bad because you're consuming twice the memory needed with this intermediate structure. It also takes more CPU to perform this operation, so its slower.
2. You are not closing your writer. Be sure to close all streams after use.
3. [Use the overload for read accepting a byte array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) instead of reading a byte at a time. Reading one byte at a time is comparatively slow.  When processing large amounts of data its noticeable.

Here's your code with the changes I suggest:

EDIT: As pointed out by c.s., you are writing to a file, and needn't convert your bytes to a string at all, as they'll just wind up as bytes again in the file. (I misread, wasn't sure you were writing to a file and so didn't include this.)

Instead of a writer, use a file output stream. I also suggest you not append a `\n` to your data as its unnecessary.

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
SharedByteArrayInputStream stream = (SharedByteArrayInputStream) content;
byte bite = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
//here we're reading more than one byte at a time.
while((bite=(byte) stream.read(buffer))!=-1){
   //write to file output stream instead.
   fileOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bite);
   //don't append new line character.
}
stream.close();
//close the output stream if you're done.
fileOutputStream.close();
```

This solution will work with any size of data, and will be much faster than your previous code.

Comment: There are 3 flaws in your answer: a) The conversion to string works only for the specific charset. If it was UTF8 you were effectively corrupting the data b) You should remove the `\n` from `writer.append()` because again you are corrupting the data but I guess this is a typo. And c) you are missing the biggest redundacy in OP code which is: you don't need to convert the bytes to string. The writer will convert again the string to bytes to write to the file. So why not write directly to a FileOutputStream? I think at least for a) you should add a note for caution

Comment: I missed that he was writing to a file.  I've edited my answer. Before I wasn't sure what writer was, and so thought maybe these things were necessary. You're right though, they are not.